# Programs failing to compile on aarch64 with `features.h: No such file or directory`

Tags: arch-linux, c++, compile, manjaro, build

I'm having trouble compiling some applications on my [PineNote](https://wiki.pine64.org/wiki/PineNote). The common thread is:

```
  /usr/include/bits/libc-header-start.h:33:10: fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory
     33 | #include <features.h>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
```

I have tried running:

```
pacman -Syu base-devel
```

Full log for ncspot failing to build can be viewed [here](https://pastebin.com/9uF72iWT). Log of thorium-reader failing to build is [here](https://pastebin.com/zaMZZXMt).

My system is:

```
Linux manjaro-arm 5.17.0-rc6-next-20220304-g18d666ad5da0 #1 SMP Mon Oct 10 08:53:33 PDT 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Pointers on how I can debug further would be helpful as well! Google searches turned up the possibility of toolchain issues, but seeing as `base-devel` is up to date, I'm not sure what to try. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: If you are being told, a compiler cannot find the header file, then you need to identify, located, and provide a path to the header file.

Comment: Ya thank you for the reply! I knew that much, but the question was if I have `base-devel` installed (which I understood should be the basic libraries necessary for most development), why am I missing `features.h`? Shouldn't `features.h` either be in `base-devel` or in the build dependencies of the specific program?

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by missing glibc.

I don't understand how I was supposed to know that glibc was required -- is that considered such a common part of the build process that it's not listed as a depends for packages? And if it's so common, why is it not in `base-devel`?

`pacman -Syu glibc` fixes the issue, but I'm not sure how I was supposed to know that I would need that package. If anyone can provide a better answer to this, it could be helpful to myself and others.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Cheers for posting this! Got the same problem, resolved it the same way. Puzzles me too, why such important/necessary component isn't included into `base-devel`.